# Is it possible to view active side quests in Infinite Undiscovery?

Tags: infinite-undiscovery

I've checked the manual, all places in the option I can think of, and the official guide, but I'm not seeing any way to view side quests that I've started.

Is there anyway to view active side quests (those that I've accepted/started) in Infinite Undiscovery?